# Microsoft SharePoint 2010 error opening Office files

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Receiving the error message:

> The file that you selected could not be found. Check the spelling of file name and verify that the location is correct. Make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using Internet Explorer 8 in **64bit Version** in relation with SharePoint 2010 and Office Web Apps.

Try using Internet Explorer in **32bit Version** to open your office files. Microsoft itself does not recommend using Internet Explorer 64bit with SharePoint, because there are no ActiceX controls for 64bit.

> Some functionality in SharePoint Server 2010 requires the use of ActiveX controls. This produces limitations on browsers which do not support ActiveX. Currently only 32-bit versions of Internet Explorer support this functionality. All other browsers have the following limitations.
>
> - [...]
> - Edit in Microsoft Office application: Microsoft Office 2010 does not provide a 64-bit version of this control.

For full list see: [TechNet: Plan browser support (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx#activex)

See also: [Office.com: Fix problems opening documents in SharePoint libraries](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/Fix-problems-opening-documents-in-SharePoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536#__toc375339305)

Comment: Thank you jcp. But, We use IE 64 bit version here. What to do?

Comment: @balarajunishani Microsoft itself does not recommend use of IE 64bit with SharePoint. So you might consider switching to 32bit Version. See my updated answer for explanations.